# C# - Cant read/load more than 256 rule pharse in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, load

I am using a c# application to read/load from a xml file

Here are the xml file content, like from this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
<GRAMMAR>
    <DEFINE>
    </DEFINE>
    <RULE NAME="HelloWorld" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE"><P>HelloWorld</P></RULE>
    <RULE NAME="HelloWorld2" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE"><P>HelloWorld2</P></RULE>
    <RULE NAME="HelloWorld3" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE"><P>HelloWorld3</P></RULE>
</GRAMMAR>
```

and so on until rule pharse HelloWorld256, my application still can read/load it, but after add the 257 rule pharse, it cant read/load anything, is there a way so i can add more than 256 rule pharse in a xml file?

Or maybe the alternative way, by open 2 xml files together, that each have 256 rule pharse, this is my c# application part, that load the grammar

> // load the grammar SAPIGrammarFromFile("XMLhelloworld.xml");

I already tried these but no one works

> // load the grammar
> SAPIGrammarFromFile("XMLhelloworld.xml");
> SAPIGrammarFromFile("XMLhelloworld2.xml");
>
> // load the grammar
> SAPIGrammarFromFile("XMLhelloworld.xml") &
> ("XMLhelloworld2.xml");
>
> // load the grammar
> SAPIGrammarFromFile("XMLhelloworld.xml" &
> "XMLhelloworld2.xml");

Please help which ever methode that can works

Answer (score 0):

Why have a 256+ rule grammar, when you noted in your [other post](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/327291-cant-readload-more-than-256-rule-pharse-in-xml-file/page__view__findpost__p__1890387) that you need it to facilitate that number of cities? The [Designing Grammar Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page shows at how to use multiple properties.